# Solutions from $\sqrt{z^2}=z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\sqrt{}:\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\sqrt{z}=exp(\frac{1}{2}Log(z))$ be the main branch of the sqaure root and Log(z) the main branch of the logarithm. For which values $z\in\mathbb{C}$ applies $\sqrt{z^2}=z$?

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have defined $\sqrt z$ only for $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$, therefore $\sqrt{z^2}$ is not defined for $z=i$ (or any purely imaginary number $z$).

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice - a second answer has appeared.

Comment: @MartinR You posted a comment just now to g's answer. How'd you do that? I can't comment on that post since it's deleted (hence I can't comment that "the usual conventions" regarding $\sqrt{}$ are irrelevant, since $\sqrt{}$ was defined to be a certain (single-valued) function at the start of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Show first that if  $w\in\Bbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$ and $z\in\Bbb C$ then

> > $\sqrt w=z$ if and only if $z^2=w$ and $z$ has positive real part.

**Since** it's been suggested that there's some problem with this, here's a proof:

First note that by definition $\sqrt w=\sqrt re^{it/2}$ if $w=re^{it}$ with $r>0$ **and** $-\pi<t<\pi$. (The constraint on $t$ follows from the definition of the *principal value* (or "main branch" in the OP) logarithm.)

Suppose first that $w=z^2$ and $z$ has positive real part. Then $z=re^{it}$ where $r>0$ and $-\pi/2<t<\pi/2$. Now $w=r^2e^{2it}$, and **since** $-\pi<2t<\pi$ this shows that $\sqrt{w}=re^{it}=z$.

Conversely, if $z=\sqrt w$ then certainly $w=z^2$; also $z=\sqrt re^{it/2}$, where $r>0$ and $-\pi<t<\pi$; hence $-\pi/2<t/2<\pi/2$, so $z$ has postive real part.

> > **Cor.** $\sqrt{z^2}=z$ if and only if  $\Re z>0$.

Proof. Note first that if $\Re z=0$ then $\sqrt{z^2}$ is undefined. Assume $\Re z\ne0$. Let $s=\sqrt{z^2}$.

Now $s^2=z^2$, so $s=\pm z$. Above we've shown that $\Re s>0$, so if $s=z$ then $\Re z>0$.
Conversely, if $\Re z>0$ then $s\ne -z$ since $\Re s>0$, hence $s=z$.